# Notation in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I have three questions on notation.

What does the squiggly line mean in the following:

$Aut(G) \cong Aut(G) \wr \mathbb{Z}_2$

What does $\rtimes$ mean in the following:

$  \varphi :(Aut(G)\times Aut(G))\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow Aut(G)$

What does $\succeq$ mean in the following:

For some monotonically increasing function $f$, $f\succeq f^m, m>1$

Comment: When you have a question like that, it's better to add some context, for example where you saw these notations.

Comment: Various parts of http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.3461&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all in the paper you mentioned.

In order:

1. $Aut(G) \cong Aut(G) \wr \mathbb{Z}_2$, and in particular the $\wr$ part, is defined at the top of page 6 as the [wreath product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product). This is a common notation, though - so that's ok.
2. $\rtimes$ is the [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product). (To be fair, this is mentioned on page 6, but it's a bit unclear that their mentioning of this relates to this symbol in particular). This is also a common notation.
3. $\succeq$ is often used to denote some sort of general ordering (as opposed to $\geq$), especially in partial orders. In this paper, it's defined after exercise 1.2 on page 2. For two functions $f, g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, they say that $f \succeq g$ if $g(n) \leq Cg(\alpha n)$ for all $n$ and some particular $C,\alpha$. This is not at all a common notation.